# Problems Parsing PHP in an HTML files on cPanel GoDaddy

Tags: php, cpanel

I'm moving a client's website from and old Linux server to a new server with cPanel, both servers are with GoDaddy and the client's html files include PHP code. (I know it's not efficient but that's how he wants it.)

On the Linux server the following lines on the .htaccess file worked:

Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .html

But on the new server, those lines are not working, I've looked everywhere and tried many different lines including the following:

AddHandler php8-script .php .html .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php8 .htm .html

Options +ExecCGI
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php8 .php .htm .html

Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .html
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php8 .html

SetHandler fcgid-script
FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .htm
Options +ExecCGI
allow from all

I also tried getting help form their customer service but they refuse to help me because according to them it is a "content issue."

If anyone can guide me how to solve the issue I'd really appreciate it.